# Show Sticky Posts at the top but do not show these posts again in the loop?

Tags: wordpress

Regarding wordpress.org

For the main loop on my homepage I want to display the sticky posts at the top BUT I don't want the post to appear again in the loop, otherwise it appears redundant to the visitor.

Problem with the below code is they remove the sticky post from the top.
I want to KEEP the sticky posts at the top
but REMOVE/EXCLUDE it from the loop. Is this possible?

CODE A: This removes sticky post from top

```
function mango($query){
if ( $query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query() && !is_admin() ) {
    $query->set( 'ignore_sticky_posts', true );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'mango' );
```

CODE B: This removes sticky post from both the top AND loop

```
function mango($query){
if ( $query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query() && !is_admin() ) {
    $query->set( 'post__not_in', get_option( 'sticky_posts' ) );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'mango' );
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you must create two loops for this. One for sticky posts and one for regular ones (but exclude sticky posts from second loop). Obviously you must put this code into **index.php**. Didn't test it but I think it should do the trick...

```
<?php //we will get "Sticky Posts" only with this loop 

    $sticky = get_option( 'sticky_posts' );

     $args = array(
    /* Add whatever you need here - see http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query */
    'post__in'  => $sticky,     
     );

$temp = $wp_query;
$wp_query = null;
$wp_query = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
<?php while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : $wp_query->the_post();
if ( empty( $sticky ) ) break;  
?>

<?php
$wp_query = null;
$wp_query = $temp;
wp_reset_query();
?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?><!--END if THE LOOP-->

<?php //Exlude stickies from second loop...
    $sticky = get_option( 'sticky_posts' );  
    $args = array(  
    'post__not_in'  => $sticky,
    );

$temp = $wp_query;
$wp_query = null;
$wp_query = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
<?php while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : $wp_query->the_post(); ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?><!--END if THE LOOP-->

<?php
$wp_query = null;
$wp_query = $temp;
wp_reset_query();
?>
```